# What is the meaning of 'columns have unit lengths'

Tags: matrices, random

What is the meaning of this?

> In random projection, the original d-dimensional data is
>   projected to a k-dimensional (k << d) subspace through
>   the origin, using a random k × d matrix R **whose columns
>   have unit lengths.**

I have already searched around the internet and can't find a straight answer.
Does it mean that each column sum of values is equal to one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Columns have unit length, typically means, the following:

If $a_i$ is the $i^{th}$ column in a matrix, then $\Vert a_i \Vert_2 = 1$, where $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ is the two-norm of a vector.

So for instance, the matrix below has columns of unit length:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1/2 & \dfrac1{\sqrt2}\\ -\dfrac12 & 0\\ -\dfrac1{\sqrt2} & \dfrac1{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}$$
since
$$\sqrt{\left(\dfrac12\right)^2 + \left(-\dfrac12\right)^2 + \left(-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\right)^2} = \sqrt{\dfrac14 + \dfrac14 + \dfrac12} = 1$$
$$\sqrt{\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\right)^2 + 0^2 + \left(\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\right)^2} = \sqrt{\dfrac12 + 0 + \dfrac12} = 1$$

Comment: So, basically speaking, the root square of the sum of the squares of each column must equal 1?

Comment: @dwbrito Yes, the two-norm is the usual length.